# How can I extract text between a pair of the same character?

Tags: python, sed, perl, awk, text-processing

Input:

```
blahŤfoobar1Ťblah
```

Desired output:

```
foobar1
```

I want to get the text between two "Ť" characters.

Assume there will always be either 0 or 2 "Ť" characters, to make things easier.

I tried the following, but I don't know how to get it to know which occurrence it is:

```
echo "blahŤfoobar1Ťblah" | sed -n '/Ť/,/Ť/p'
```

Comment: You can use a simple cut command - `echo "blah@foobar1@blah" | cut -f2 -d"@"`

Comment: You should relocate this to the answer portion!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a cut command.

To extract the second pattern:

`echo "blah@foobar1@blah" | cut -f2 -d"@"`

To extract the second and third patterns:

`echo "blah@foobar1@blah" | cut -f2,3 -d"@"`

To extract from the second pattern onwards

`echo "blah@foobar1@blah" | cut -f2- -d"@"`

EDIT: Since the question was tagged with awk. Here is an awk solution.

```
echo "blah@foobar1@blah" | awk -F'@' {'print $2'}
```

Comment: I'm sorry to change the question on you, I was trying to simplify it a bit with a familiar character. But the cut method does not work if I use the "Ť" character.

Comment: Aahhh perfect, I'm so glad you put the awk variant, it worked with awk! I will mark it as solved as soon as it lets me, cheers @rahul.

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`

```
echo "blahŤfoobar1Ťblah" | sed  -r 's/(^.*Ť)(.*)(Ť.*$)/\2/'
```

output

```
foobar1
```

Another possible way using `sed`

```
echo "blahŤfoobar1Ťblah" | sed -r 's/.*Ť(.*)Ť.*/\1/'
```

output

```
foobar1
```

*Thanks for @kos for the `-r` note*

Comment: Why the `-e` switch on the first command? Also you might use `-r` to get rid of the escaping ``\`` before the parenthesis

Comment: I dont think that matter anymore, the original was slightly different, now I can remove it `-e`. Thanks for note..

Answer (score 2):

`awk` likes these things:

```
$ awk -F"Ť" '{print $2}' <<< "blahŤfoobar1Ťblah"
foobar1
```

By using `Ť` as field separator, we make sure we catch the desired text in the second block. If we would like to skip the processing if no `Ť` is found in a given line, we could use `awk -F"Ť" 'NF>1{print $2}'`.

---

Regarding your attempt not working: by saying `sed -n '/start/,/end/p'` your are printing those lines that are between (and included) a line containing `start` and another containing `end`. So it would work if you wanted this.

#### Example

Given this file:

```
$ cat a
starting...
Ť
foobar1
hello
Ť
i am here
```

The output is:

```
$ sed -n '/Ť/,/Ť/p' a
Ť
foobar1
hello
Ť
```

Answer (score 2):

`awk` seems to be the easiest to use for this problem:

```
$ echo "blahŤfoobar1Ťblah" | awk -FŤ '{ print $2 }'
foobar1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `perl` to extract the text:

```
$ echo 'blahŤfoobar1Ťblah' | perl -FŤ -ane 'print"$F[1]\n"'
foobar1
```

Here the key is to use the `-F` option to set the delimiter.

Another approach using a regular expression:

```
$ echo "blahŤfoobar1Ťblah" | perl -pe 's/.*Ť(.*)Ť.*/$1/' 
foobar1
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Using `bash` :

   ```
   $ test='blahŤfoobar1Ťblah'
   $ spamegg="${test#*Ť}"
   $ echo "${spamegg%Ť*}"
   foobar1
   ```

   Here we have used the `bash` parameter expansion get the desired substring.

   - `"${test#*Ť}"` will remove the portion `blahŤ` , so the variable `spamegg` will have `foobar1Ťblah`
   - `${spamegg%Ť*}` will remove the trailing `Ťblah`, so we would get the output `foobar1`
2. Using `grep` :

   ```
       $ echo "blahŤfoobar1Ťblah" | grep -Po '(?<=Ť)[^Ť]+(?=Ť)'
       foobar1
   ```

   - `-P` implements the `perl` compatible Regex, `-o` prints only the matched portion
   - `(?<=Ť)` is the zero width positive look behind pattern ensuring there will be a `Ť` prior to the match
   - `(?=Ť)` is the zero width positive lookahead pattern ensuring there is a `Ť` following the match
   - `[^Ť]+` will match one or more characters between the two `Ť` characters.
3. Using `python` :

   ```py
   $ python2 -c "print 'blahŤfoobar1Ťblah'.split('Ť')[1]"
   foobar1
   ```

   - `split()` will split the string into list of fields separated by `Ť` and the we have printed the second element from the list.